# Remove Margin(vertical) between rows in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to remove ugly verical spacing between bootstrap rows below:
[image]

The code is:

```html
<div class="outerbox container-fluid vw-100">
  <div class="row vw-100 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-7 " style=" background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45);
            box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(31, 38, 135, 0.37);
            backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);">
      <div class="optionrow row justify-content-center py-0">
        <div class="col-8">
          <a href="f1/f1.html">
            <div class="option">Function 1</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="optionrow row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-8">
          <a href="f2/f2.html">
            <div class="option">Function 2</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="optionrow row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-8">
          <a href="f3/f3.html">
            <div class="option">Function 3</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="optionrow row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-8">
          <a href="Past Question Papers/past papers.html">
            <div class="option">Past Papers</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is some CSS for link transition:

```css
.option {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px;
            border: unset;
            border-radius: 15px;
            color: black;
            z-index: 1;
            background: #e8e8e8;
            position: relative;
            font-weight: 1000;
            font-size: 14px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 8px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
            box-shadow: 4px 8px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
            transition: all 250ms;
            overflow: hidden;

        }

        .option::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 0;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background-color: #212121;
            z-index: -1;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 8px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
            box-shadow: 4px 8px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
            transition: all 250ms
        }

        .option:hover {
            color: #e8e8e8;
        }

        .option:hover::before {
            width: 100%;
        }
```

I have tried `!important` CSS but it's not working:

```css
.optionrow {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.optionrow a {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

It seems like the reason for this is some Bootstrap functionality.

I want it to look like this:
[The webpage showing desired layout](https://vishvjeet79.github.io/website/)

Comment: Not a direct solution, but can you put all the content that would be separate rows, together in a single row? You could then separate them using whatever spacing you so desire.

Comment: @GetSet I can, but this configuration was the only one where  1. divs were centered within their parent,  2. the whole div was clickable instead of just the ink text  3. The link hover tranisition was working correctly.      I have not been able to get all the desired results otherwise.    Although I do have the desired result as shown  in    https://vishvjeet79.github.io/website/    but I am trying mobile first design and therefore want to use bootstrap.    When I finally got everything, this new issue of ugly spacing emerged.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not find any solution for the vertical spacing between the rows.
However, I solved the the problem I was facing
The new code is simpler although I did not understand the actual mechanincs   but its working so thats fine as of now

```html
<div class="outerbox container-fluid vw-100">
  <div class="row vw-100 justify-content-center">
    <div class=" col-sm-10 col-md-7 col-lg-6 " style=" background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45);
            box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(31, 38, 135, 0.37);
            backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);">
      <div class="optionrow row justify-content-center py-2">
        <a class="col-8 option" href="f1/f1.html">Function 1</a>
        <a class="col-8 option" href="f1/f1.html">Function 1</a>
        <a class="col-8 option" href="f1/f1.html">Function 1</a>
        <a class="col-8 option" href="f1/f1.html">Function 1</a>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to add the `gy-0` for vertical gutter (gap) to define that you're not interested in having the default gutters between the rows.
[enter link description here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/)

Hope this solves your problem, have a great day!

Comment: tried 'gy-0' in row, still no change     but maybe thats because the documentation says gutter is for columns within a row.